# Blender 2.71 Preview Showing Incorrectly

Tags: texturing, interface, uv

I am tinkering with UV mapping a skybox onto a cube (sideways T shape image)

So with the UV map settings and the actual render working correctly, I've been noticing the preview box in cube. It looks like this:

[image]

How do I fix it to show the texture wrapping around?

Answer (score 2):

The preview is unlikely to match the finished render because you are using UV mapping. To have the preview cube match the finished render would require the preview cube to be using the same uv mapping that you are using. The preview isn't able to do this because it isn't aware what object the material is being applied to and has no connection to your object.

The material preview is used to answer the question "What would my material look like if it were applied to different objects?" but not "What will the material look like on my specific object?" The fact that your object, a cube, looks like the preview, also a cube, is just coincidence.

Setting the viewport to 'Rendered' shading mode is the best way to preview how the material will look on *your* object.

Comment: I like the suggestion/information  regarding the best way to preview in [Rendered Shading Mode].  It went beyond the original question and is still related.  In this forum we probably cannot directly change or "fix" this preview aspect of blender as the question was posed.  The suggestion/information allows the user to think differently and productively about the problem with related techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You render works correctly. You are successful and golden.  The preview is to get some quick, low cost, color and transparency sense of a material.  If you model the Eiffel Tower it will not show up in the Material Texture preview as a Small Eiffel Tower.  If I model a sphere I can select the Monkey preview.

Lastly as your question was posed probably no one except software developers can change or "fix" the preview.  It may be difficult to even find some precise written specification for the preview.  So I am certainly not in the position to [say] that any change would "fix" anything to any large consensus because I did not create the specification.  The value of the preview had been validated by years of experienced users.

Comment: I would expect off-results if you used a monkey preview on a spherical mesh. But I'm explicitly doing a simple textured cube which I would expect the preview to show it kind of right, rather than simply showing the entire skybox image once per side.

Obviously, as you said, I'm golden, since everything renders fine. But sometimes if something in the interface looks a bit off, in blender that tends to bite me.

Comment: @user6325 I understand your point of view.  I consider blender to be quite useful.  For the first number of months of learning [some] blender I felt like blender and its documentation were pure ev...  I have deep bite marks too.  Mostly on face and neck.